# Table view cell not showing in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have this View Controller (see code below) linked to a table view controller storyboard. I get the actual table view showing but not my custom cell. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Good to know:
- I have a separate swift file specifically made for my cell
- I have connected the cell with a cell identifier
- This is not my main view controller.

Thanks in advance!

```
import UIKit


class ForecastTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var forecasts = [Forecast]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return forecasts.count 
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "forecastCell", for: indexPath) as? ForecastCell {

        let forecast = forecasts[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(forecast: forecast)
        return cell

    } else {

        return ForecastCell()

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Given `delegate` and `datasource` to `UITableView`?

Comment: Have you set tableview's delegate and datasource.

Comment: I have done that now, still won't work

Comment: try with static count under `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: Are you sure forecasts is not an empty array?

Answer (score 4):

Add below lines in `viewDidload` above reload function,

```
  self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
```

And no need of `self.tableView.reloadData()` in `viewDidload` so remove it!

Comment: I have now added the lines. But I get the error "Value of type 'UITableView' has not member 'datasource'." And adding UITableViewDataSource to the class does not work since it already is a UITableViewController.

Comment: it is `dataSource` not `datasource`. It was a typo!!

Answer (score 1):

Put this inside your `viewDidLoad()` method

```
self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "ForecastCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "forecastCell")
```

Also make sure that you actually set the cell's identifier not restoration ID (common mistake)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Still not working though... As I said, I get the table view but not my custom cell. I figure to maybe redo the whole cell and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you register your cell, if not register it first.

```
tableView.registerClass(MyCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: kCellIdentifier)
```

OR if you are using cell with Xib then register

```
self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "UICustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "UICustomTableViewCell")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I wrote the following code, and I do not receive any errors. 'tableView.register(ForecastCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "forecastCell")' But the cell still won't work...

Comment: check the identifier assigned to cell and you have to any one of above two. are you creating custom with xib or in storybaord?

Comment: The identifier is "forecastCell" and I am not using Xib, so I went with your first recommendation.

Comment: if everything seems fine then do one delete table from storyboard and connect everything again.

Comment: I kept just below code for testing it's working, check this,.                     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("forecastCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        
       return cell
    }

Comment: I tried this on an another project, and as you said it works just fine. Also as you said I should probably try to reconnect everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code in this way and remember to put your data inside your `forecasts` array

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "forecastCell", for: indexPath) as? ForecastCell 

        let forecast = forecasts[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(forecast: forecast)
        return cell

    }
```